# Why does Matlab not evaluate a symbolic expression when using subs()?

Tags: matlab

This is the code along with the output.

```
>> syms x
>> y=-(x-2*sin(x))/(1-2*cos(x))

y =

    (x - 2*sin(x))/(2*cos(x) - 1)

>> x=1.9

x =

    1.9000

>> subs(y)

ans =

  -(2*sin(19/10) - 19/10)/(2*cos(19/10) - 1)
```

I can't figure out why this absurd answer is coming. I am not able to fix it.

So far I have tried taking `y` also as a symbolic variable and using `int(ans)` , with no success. I have also tried storing `ans` in a non-symbolic variable, but the same output shows up every time.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [`double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html) on the result to evaluate the symbolic expression and get a numeric value:

```
>> out = double(subs(y))

out =

  -0.004494059516242
```

Comment: True, I was not able to find this in documentation. :) Next time I'll look hard enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`subs` will substitute the value in your expression, but it will stay symbolic and will not be computed. In order to get the value numerically you need `eval` instead of `subs`.

Answer (score 0):

eval(subs(...)) also work. I don't know what is better to use eval either double, my teacher uses double